# Load google map dynamicly in twitter bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm Trying to add a map dynamically inside a modal window of a twitter bootstrap but it dose not seem to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style type="text/css">
  #map-canvas  {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#map-canvas {
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body  >

        <h1 class="">Lazy Load Google Map</h1> 
<a href="javascript:;" class="view" data-lat="23, 18.33">Launch Map Modal</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myMapModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="map-canvas" class=""></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal -->

        <script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



        <script type='text/javascript' src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script type='text/javascript' src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&extension=.js&output=embed"></script>





        <script type='text/javascript'>

        $(".view").click(function(){
            var element = $(this);

        var map;        
            var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(element.attr("data-lat"));
var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    position:myCenter
});
$('#myMapModal').modal('show');

function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
      center:myCenter,
      zoom: 14,
      draggable: false,
      scrollwheel: false,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapProp);
  marker.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);

  }); 
};
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", resizingMap());
$('#myMapModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
   //Must wait until the render of the modal appear, thats why we use the resizeMap and NOT resizingMap!! ;-)
   resizeMap();
})

function resizeMap() {
   if(typeof map =="undefined") return;
   setTimeout( function(){resizingMap();} , 400);
}

function resizingMap() {
   if(typeof map =="undefined") return;
   var center = map.getCenter();
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
   map.setCenter(center); 
}

            });



        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Take a look at this example: http://www.bootply.com/zhqU9Vhu4k

Comment: I have seen it, The thing is i want to load the map dynamically  from a list of locations by the appropriate link

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open modal Via data attributes

```
<a href="#" data-lat="23, 18.33" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myMapModal">
   Launch Map Modal
</a>
```

create function initialize with parameter(parameters)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var element = $(this);
    var map;

    function initialize(myCenter) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myCenter
        });

      var mapProp = {
            center: myCenter,
            zoom: 10,
            //draggable: false,
            //scrollwheel: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapProp);
        marker.setMap(map);
    };
</script>
```

on shown.bs.modal event call it with parameter that you get from invoker button ($(e.relatedTarget))

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $('#myMapModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
        var element = $(e.relatedTarget);
        var data = element.data("lat").split(',')
        initialize(new google.maps.LatLng(data[0], data[1]));
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I've added `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` after         `initialize(new google.maps.LatLng(data[0], data[1]));` after that it works like a charm thank you :)

Comment: Nice solution. Thank you for sharing.

(worked perfect for me without adding a resize)